# Why shouldn't the button element be a descendant of the anchor element?

Tags: html

Part of HTMl code uses a button that is used to navigate to a different route in flask hence I wrap it in an anchor tag like so:

```
 <a href="/deleteAccount" id="deleteAccount"><button>Delete Account</button></a>
```

When passing my HTML through the W3C validator I get the following error:
"The element button must not appear as a descendant of the a element."

What is the reason for this error?  Writing my code this way achieves the desired effect of navigating through the use a button without having to instead style an anchor tag or use javascript unnecessarily.

Comment: What's the point of the button element if it's within a link? If you need the look of a button, simply use CSS to style your anchor

Answer (score 3):

In blunt terms:

Because the HTML spec forbids it.

---

In logical terms:

A link is an interactive control for navigating to a new page.

A button is an interactive control for submitting a form (unless you change the type in which case it becomes a control for resetting a form or just triggering a JS click event).

It doesn't make sense for one click to do both of those things at once.

---

If you want a link that looks like a button. Then style a link to look like a button. (But think hard about if that is a good idea, because a button is a UI control that users expect to *do something* and not just *navigate somewhere*.)